# c# equivalent code in java for RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignData()

Tags: java, c#, signature

I need to replicate the C# code to generate a encrypted string.
C# code is as below

```
private RSACryptoServiceProvider m_rsa;
m_rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
m_rsa.FromXmlString(privKey);//privKey is from properties file
string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(m_rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Original Text to Encrypt"), "SHA1"));
```

I tried Java code as below with the help of some goolgle searcha nd stackouver flow but I am getting different encrypted i.e not matching with the c# generated.

```
String modulusString = "yJNZfy7lMF/O9N......=";//shorted for better view
String privateExponentString = "AQAB";
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(modulusString);
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(privateExponentString);
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
BigInteger privateExponent = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);
RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrvKey =new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulus, privateExponent); 
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");        
PrivateKey privateKey = fact.generatePrivate(rsaPrvKey);

Base64 base64Encoder = new Base64();//Base64 is from apache commons codec as I am using java 1.7
byte[] encBytes = tocrypt.getBytes("UTF-8");
Signature sig=Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithRSA");
sig.initSign(privateKey);
sig.update(encBytes);
String encrypted = new String(base64Encoder.encode(sig.sign()));
System.out.println(encrypted);
```

Please help me where is the mistake.

thanks and regards,

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: 1) You are signing data, not encrypting. 2) Use the private exponent to build the private key. You are using the public exponent

Comment: 1)yes after signing the data I am encoding with base64. the result of the base64 encoding is different in java and c#.  2) I don't understand where I am using public exponent instead of private exponent.

Comment: AQAB is the public exponent

Comment: Then where I find the Private Exponent?